# Android logcat errors TundConnector and NetlinkEvent

Tags: android, logcat

I just noticed in my LogCat I am getting consistent errors (about every second) and wondering if anyone could shed some light on the problem?  Droid X2 w/ newest update.

```
10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482): Communications error
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:238)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:98)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:99)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:83)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482): Error in NativeDaemonConnector
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:238)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:98)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:99)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:83)
    10-21 14:52:49.590: ERROR/TundConnector(1482):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

And I am seeing this one a lot as well:

```
10-21 14:55:27.856: ERROR/NetlinkEvent(1351): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UDEV_LOG' not found
```

Comment: What is your OS, phone type, software version, do you have custom ROM installed...?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found any real solution to, even cause for this. But I have found a way to make logcat useable with these errors, use the following regex in Logcat:

```
tag:[^((TundConnector)|(NetlinkEvent))]
```

That will give you everything in the log that is *NOT* tagged as either **TundConnector** or **NetlinkEvent**

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart eclipse, I meet the same problem, after I restart eclipse, the problem is solved.