# Tund connector error : ERROR/TundConnector(1475): Communications error in android

Tags: android

I am getting the below error

10-28 15:55:48.252: ERROR/NetlinkEvent(1347): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UDEV_LOG' not found
10-28 15:55:48.442: ERROR/NetlinkEvent(1347): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UDEV_LOG' not found
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475): Communications error
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:238)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:98)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:99)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:83)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475): Error in NativeDaemonConnector
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:238)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:98)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:99)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:83)
10-28 15:55:49.082: ERROR/TundConnector(1475):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Is there any settings needs to be done or is it because of the 3G or wifi connectivity?
Please confirm.

Thanks,
Pallavi Roy

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any real solution to, even cause for this. But I have found a way to make logcat useable with these errors, use the following regex in Logcat:

```
tag:[^((TundConnector)|(NetlinkEvent))]
```

That will give you everything in the log that is *NOT* tagged as either **TundConnector** or **NetlinkEvent**

*This question is pretty much a dup of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854029/android-logcat-errors-tundconnector-and-netlinkevent/)*